# Creating an object on canvas with a mouseclick - at the same time not making the old objects disappear

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

With the aid of some tutorials I wrote code that creates a circle (of a different color and of a different size every time) when the mouse is clicked. When a new circle is created, the old one disappears. How can I change this code to achieve the effect of old circles remaining on the canvas when new ones are being created?

```
public class Main {

    private static int x, y;
    private static draw object = new draw();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mouse");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 400);
        frame.add(object);
        object.addMouseListener(new AL());
    }
    static class AL extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            object.drawing(x, y);
        }
    }
}

class draw extends JPanel {

    private static int x, y;
    public void drawing (int xx, int yy) {
        x = xx;
        y = yy;
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics j) {
        super.paintComponent(j);
        Random rand = new Random();

        float r = rand.nextFloat();
        float g = rand.nextFloat();
        float b = rand.nextFloat();

        Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);
        int k = rand.nextInt(150);
        j.setColor(randomColor);
        j.fillOval(x - k/2, y - k/2, k, k);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Keep a `List` of them. In the paint component method, iterate the list & paint each one. 2) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). Also, don't generate random values in a painting method. You can't control when the paintComponent() method will be invoked.